# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.xl.entity.Users

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Here is the code:

```
public Users login(String username) {
        Users user=null;
        try {
            String hql="select user.name,user.password from Users user where user.name=:name";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setString("name", username);
            user=(Users) query.list().get(0);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Error：

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.xl.entity.Users
    at com.xl.impl.HouseDaoImpl.login(HouseDaoImpl.java:51)
    at com.xl.biz.HouseBiz.login(HouseBiz.java:25)
    at com.xl.Servlet.UserServlet.doGet(UserServlet.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

(Translations courtesy Google Translate)

Comment: it is good to select `hibernet` tag also

Comment: What is the question? You might want to consider looking at the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) page for some examples on what to include in your questions. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the Users object, edit your query to be like

```
String hql="from Users user where user.name=:name";
```

Otherwise the result will be an array of objects so you need to either use a transformer or simply cast it to object[]:

```
String hql="select user.password from Users user where user.name=:name";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setString("name", username);
Object[] result =(Object[]) query.list().get(0);
String password = result[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another constructor for `Users` as `public Users(String name, String password)` and change query to

```
String hql="select new yourpath.Users(user.name,user.password) from Users user
where user.name=:name";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) backed on root entity in this manner

```
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setResultTransformer(RootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
query.list()
```

Using a projection (the select list) will produce a result of `Object[]` type: the `ResultTransformer` will create a `User` object and maps raw `Object[]` to correct `User`'s property

Answer (score -1):

Since `query.list()` returns `List`, and here you are casting the content of the list to type `User`, Now, as exception says `Object can not be cast to User`. Please make sure, are you getting the content in form of user.

You can make a check:

```
 if(query.list() instanceOf User){
        // can cast to user.
 }else{
        // can not cast to User.
 }
```

Comment: No need to do it, hql should be just fixed or return different data type.